# Dual boot failure

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7

My problem is this: I've installed Ubuntu on a W7 laptop with the intention operate as a dual boot. However, upon a restart it goes directly into W7 never having offered a choice to OS's. I've gone online for advice but I find the suggestions VERY confusing, owing to my complete lack of experience with Ubuntu.

Comment: Can you boot to Ubuntu by using the BIOS boot menu?

Comment: I have a few questions before I can answer your question.

Is Windows 7 installed in UEFI mode? Or in Legacy mode? What about Ubuntu? Did you try to switch priority from UEFI to Legacy or vice-versa in the BIOS settings? Did you get errors while installing Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Few points:

1. If Windows 7 is installed in UEFI mode you need to install Ubuntu
   also in UEFI mode.
2. Disable Secure boot completely in BIOS.
3. In your case Ubuntu is already installed so try to login into Ubuntu
   and do a boot-repair(previous 2 points must be completed before
   doing this)

Once in Ubuntu, in terminal(Ctrl+Alt+T)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

For more info, refer [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Answer (score 0):

at first install the free software 'EasyBCD' (current version is 2.2) in your windows 7 system. Then run it. In EasyBCD, click on "**Add New Entry**" and select "**Linux/BSD**" and change the type to "**GRUB 2**" and name it "**Ubuntu**". And then Click on "**Add Entry**". Go to "Edit Boot Menu" and click on "**Save settings**". And then you are good to go. You can also change the order of boot menu during power up from the "Edit Boot Menu" option.
[image: EasyBCD Screen]